# I can connect to the internet only while my router is resetting

Tags: networking, router, internet-connection, fios

I recently upgraded to the Fios quantum router. I host a small website from my desktop, so I was trying to setup port forwarding on my router when I realized I had lost my internet connection. The globe icon on the front turned red. I'm not sure if I screwed something up by messing around, or I physically hit something when I picked up the router to read the admin password.

I've tried turning it off and on (didn't help), so I reset the router entirely by sticking a pin in the back. Then I noticed that I could access the internet (my desktop is connected via Ethernet), but only while it's in the process of resetting! Once it finishes resetting it turns red again and I lose my connection.

I can also log into the setup page for the router (the thing on 192.168.1.1) and it says "Ethernet/Coax status: disabled". I have another box plugged into the router (the ONT?) so there's nothing plugged into the coax.

Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: I can only recommend that the first thing you do after resetting your router is to log into it and change the default login information.

Comment: @mael' will this help, or are you just saying I should do this as a security measure?

Comment: both, actually - if you're hosting a website on your desktop that means people have to go through your network to access your website's data. how exactly are you hosting it? I recommend turning off your hosting service and then seeing if you still have the issue with your Internet dropping out.

Comment: I've stopped running the server, but I do still have dynamic DNS set up to redirect to my IP (well, I guess not since my internet went down) but I assumed that by itself couldn't affect anything.